# BootCamp partition disappeared

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, bootcamp, partition

Running Macbook Pro with snow leopard, I partitioned with bootcamp assistant to install dual boot between MacOS and windows 7. However, now it shows that my Mac Hard Disk is 499 GB, but available only 303 GB, but the partition of 100GB that I made for win7 doesnt show up anywhere.

Where should I look for the missing partition?

Comment: Does it show in Disk Utility?

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot find it in disk utility, then it probably has become empty space. Then all you have to do is repartition (via disk utility) your OSX partition so it takes up the entire drive again. If that doesn't work, backup your system, and format the entire drive when reinstalling Snow Leopard, and restore afterwards.

Comment: Hello abc905, the lost partition doesnt show in the disk utility, or in bootcamp assistant. I dont have any CD with the Mac. How do I re-install the OSX?